# Fix the structure of a Label

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to fix the structure of a label in Neo4j? For example, fix the label:

```
Person {
    name : String,
    lastname : String
}
```

Then:

```
(p1:Person {name:"Jhon", lastname:"Doe"}) --> OK

(p2:Person {name:"Jenny", lastname:"Doe", age:"18"}) --> error
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no way to require certain properties (or prevent others) for a specific label.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's what I was afraid of ... thanks

Comment: You can require them in the enterprise edition ( [property existence constraints](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-constraints-prop-exist-nodes) ) but can't prevent or limit others.

Comment: So, we can be sure that the node will contains value but we can't protect against new one ? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to achieve this would be implementing a `TransactionEventHandler`. See https://maxdemarzi.com/2015/03/25/triggers-in-neo4j/ for a great write up on this.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, It's a bit big for what I would implements but it give me an idea of how to do it